# Optimize complex MySQL selects for reporting

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, subquery

I'm building an application in which,

a) each librarian can create a campaign
b) actions carried out as part of that campaign are tracked in `campaign_actions`, actions being page loads

In order to report on the number of actions made in each campaign, [I wrote this SQL query (for MySQL)](https://gist.github.com/913753) for the following database structure, with the intention of tracking the number of actions undertaken by a librarian for each campaign:

```
LIBRARIANS
id | status

CAMPAIGNS
id | librarian_id

CAMPAIGN_ACTIONS
id | campaign_id | name
```

The problems I am having are:

a) I have to specify the fields I want to count in the correlated subselects
b) The query will be quite expensive as a result

My question is, since there are multiple actions for a campaign, how can I effectively **count** the number of actions **per** campaign in a more efficient manner?

Less complex queries amount to returning a result set like so:

```
  librarians.id   |  librarians.status  |  campaign_actions.name
       1                    3                     pageX
       1                    3                     pageY
       1                    3                     pageZ
       1                    3                     pageA
       1                    3                     pageB
       2                    3                     pageX
```

which means i'd have to parse the result set in application code row by row, which is likely to be *more* expensive.

I appreciate any thoughts you may have on this problem.

Comment: I suggest you break the task into smaller ones. One (view) to count campaigns per librraian, one to count campaign actions per campaign, etc. Then use which of them you need, JOINing them with your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking the task into smaller tasks (views):

```
--- campaings per librarian
CREATE VIEW count_librarian_campaigns
AS ( SELECT lib.id AS lib_id
          , COUNT(c.id)
                   AS num_campaigns
     FROM librarians lib
     LEFT JOIN campaigns c
       ON c.librarian_id = lib.id
     GROUP BY lib.id
   )

--- campaign actions per campaign
CREATE VIEW count_campaign_actions
AS ( SELECT c.id   AS c_id
          , COUNT(ca.campaign_id)
                   AS num_actions
     FROM campaigns c
     LEFT JOIN campaign_actions ca
       ON ca.campaign_id = c.id
     GROUP BY c.id
   )
```

So, you could have queries like this:

```
SELECT lib.id AS lib_id
     , countlibc.num_campaigns
     , c.id   AS c_id 
     , countca.num_actions
FROM librarians lib
JOIN count_librarian_campaigns countlibc
  ON countlibc.lib_id = lib.id
LEFT JOIN campaigns c
  ON c.librarian_id = lib.id
JOIN count_campaign_actions countca
  ON countca.c_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for your purposes?

```
SELECT librarians_id,COUNT(librarians_id) FROM (
    SELECT librarians.id as librarians_id,
            librarians.status as librarians_status,
            campaign_actions.name as campaign_actions_name
    FROM campaign_actions
    INNER JOIN campaigns
           ON campaign_actions.campaign_id = campaigns.id
    INNER JOIN librarians
           ON campaigns.librarian_id = librarians.id
    GROUP BY campaign_actions.name,librarians.id,librarians.status ) as a
```

Maybe I misunderstood what you're after. The inner query seems like it would return the table you represented above.